# Unity Save Load Function: Using Application.persistentDataPath

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, save

I'm a beginner Unity developer.
I've made Save & Load function using an asset that supports the storage function.
It is a common way to save it by creating a file in the form of Json in the Application.personDataPath/ folder.

The problem is that it works perfectly well in Unity Editor, but it doesn't when I build it as a complete game. When I look up in Application.persistantDataPath/, which is target folder, nothing is created.

Is there a solution or a diagnostic method that you use often?

​For more information, look at the code below.
I've used Asset called 'Corgi Engine' that I've bought from the Unity Asset Store.

**Setting the path for file**

```
/// the method to use when saving and loading files (has to be the same at both times of course)

public static IMMSaveLoadManagerMethod saveLoadMethod = new MMSaveLoadManagerMethodBinary();

/// the default top level folder the system will use to save the file

private const string _baseFolderName = "/MMData/";

/// the name of the save folder if none is provided

private const string _defaultFolderName = "MMSaveLoadManager";

​

/// <summary>

/// Determines the save path to use when loading and saving a file based on a folder name.

static string DetermineSavePath(string folderName = _defaultFolderName)

{

string savePath;

// depending on the device we're on, we assemble the path

if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)

{

savePath = Application.persistentDataPath + _baseFolderName;

} 

else 

{

savePath = Application.persistentDataPath + _baseFolderName;

}

#if UNITY_EDITOR

savePath = Application.dataPath + _baseFolderName;

#endif

​

savePath = savePath + folderName + "/";

return savePath;

}
```

**Creating directory and saving**

```
/// <summary>

/// Save the specified saveObject, fileName and foldername into a file on disk.

public static void Save(object saveObject, string fileName, string foldername = _defaultFolderName)

{

string savePath = DetermineSavePath(foldername);

string saveFileName = DetermineSaveFileName(fileName);

// if the directory doesn't already exist, we create it

if (!Directory.Exists(savePath))

{

Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath);

}

// we serialize and write our object into a file on disk

​

FileStream saveFile = File.Create(savePath + saveFileName);

​

saveLoadMethod.Save(saveObject, saveFile);

saveFile.Close();

}
```

**Converting to Json and Saving**

```
/// <summary>

/// Saves the specified object at the specified location after converting it to json

public void Save(object objectToSave, FileStream saveFile)

{

string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(objectToSave);

// if you prefer using NewtonSoft's JSON lib uncomment the line below and commment the line above

//string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToSave);

StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(saveFile);

streamWriter.Write(json);

streamWriter.Close();

saveFile.Close();

Debug.Log(objectToSave.GetType());

}
```

Comment: Hadn't used StreamWriter, but for Unity I normally just use `System.IO.File.WriteAllText ( pathWhereToStore, JsonUtility.ToJson ( objectToSave ) )`

Answer (score 0):

As your code says, you use `Application.dataPath` (Assets folder) in editor mode, while in Android and iOS the `Application.persistentDataPath` is used. That’s why the result is different.

See the docs for the [first](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) and [second](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html). Look where the file should be stored in each case.

If you still can’t find your files in Android, try runtime debugging - run `Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath);` or just assign it to some text object in the scene